# how to get paddles to stop at window bounds

Tags: c++

so i have written code for a pong clone and i am working on getting the paddles to stop from going beyond the window bounds.  heres the code i am using

```
if (this->getPosition().y < 0)
    {
        this->move(0, 1.0f);
    }
    else if (this->getPosition().y + this->getGlobalBounds().height > 600);
    {
        this->move(0, -1.0f);
    }
```

no when i do this the paddles wont move towards the bottom but will move towards the top and go off screen. when i comment out the this->move(0, -1.0f) the paddles will stop at the top of the screen but will move off the screen at the bottom. heres the header file its in:

```
#pragma once
#include "entity.h"

class paddle_player : public Entity
{
public: 
paddle_player(int playerNumber)
{
    this->playerNumber = playerNumber;
    switch (this->playerNumber)
    {
        case 0:
            this->Load("paddle1.png");
            break;
        default:
            this->Load("paddle2.png");

            break;
    }
}
void Update()
{
    switch (this->playerNumber)
    {
    case 0:
        this->velocity.y = sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::S) - sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::W);
        break;
    default:
        this->velocity.y = sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Down) - sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Up);
        break;



    }
    Entity::Update();
    if (this->getPosition().y < 0)
    {
        this->move(0, 1.0f);
    }
    else if (this->getPosition().y + this->getGlobalBounds().height > 600);
    {
        this->move(0, -1.0f);
    }
}
private:
int playerNumber; 
};
```

i dont know what else to include but please help!

Comment: There's an extra semicolon after `else if(...)` so it means "else if this then do nothing. Then always move the paddle up."

Comment: i changed to just an if statement but still same thing

Comment: But did you fix the semicolon?

Comment: hahaha thats what i love about this shit. makes you feel dumb as hell but then kinda like ok that was small but still messes up everything!  thanks for the help/